# Wordpress not loading my stylesheet

Tags: php, wordpress

For some reason, this code in my functions.php file isn't working for my custom Wordpress Theme:

```
<?php 
add_theme_support('menus');

function mySite_scripts(){
 wp_enqueue_style('test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/base.css');
}

 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','mySite_scripts');
?>
```

My Theme is located in the **wp-content/themes/mySite/css** folder and is called **base.css** but when I save the file and run it, the stylesheet isn't being loaded for some strange reason :(

Could anyone help me please?

PS: Just in case, my **index.php** file looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes();?> >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><?php echo bloginfo('title');?></title>
    </?php wp_head();?>
</head>

<body>
    <?php get_header();?>

    <h1>My Site</h1>
    <?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/base.css';?>

    <?php get_footer();?>
    <?php wp_footer();?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_template_directory_uri()` returns the base theme directory so in essence it returns `http://yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/mySite/`. You need to add `css/` to the path so it becomes:

```
wp_enqueue_style('test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/base.css');
```

Comment: Hi Irvin,

I just changed the line to say: 
`wp_enqueue_style('test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/base.css');` but it still doesn't work I'm afraid.

Comment: just to confirm, the current theme folder is `mySite`? could you try accessing the URL that is output from `echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/base.css'` and see if you can access the css file?

Comment: Yep, the css file is displayed when I go to:
`http://localhost/florrie/wp-content/themes/florrie/css/base.css` 

it's odd how it's not linking the file in though from the **functions.php** file

Comment: found a really bad typo on your part: `</?php wp_head();?>` should be `<?php wp_head();?>`... hope it works now!!!!

Comment: .... :o .. you have GOT to be kidding me!  I do not believe it, lol. Irvin, thank you so SO much, you sir are a life saver. This has been driving me crazy for the last hour and a half. I hate myself, lol :)  Thanks again my good man, you're a star! All working now :D

Comment: you're welcome :) i suggest you get a coffee or some sleep, but not both at the same time :)

Comment: Haha, I think a coffee right now is exactly what I need :) Thanks again for your help.